# How to make turtles at a specific (unknown) point do something in netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to make a turtle at a specific point (with is another blue turtle) do something, namely become blessed. (which means it can reproduce).

I tried using at-point, but the point is the position of the blue turtles is random, so it is unknown.

So I tried something else, but that didn't work either.

```
ask food [ask n-of count ants-on food [set blessed true]]
```

I also tried this:

```
ask food [ask ants in-radius 1 [set blessed true]]
```

but then the all the turtles became blessed, when only one of them was it the radius.

Also

```
 ask ants [if ants-on food [set blessed true]]
```

Did not work.

Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: how is the unknown point actually defined - for example, is it a specific blue turtle? are you wanting something like `ask turtles with [color = blue] [ask ants in-radius 1 [set blessed true]]`. It is also unclear what food has to do with anything here - does the food confer blessings?

Comment: It is a turtle with the color blue, but when I try this, all the ants will become blessed and not only the ones on the blue turtle. So I have two turtles. One with the color brown (the ant, the one that must become blessed) and a blue one (which the ant has to touch before it becomes blessed).

Comment: so you want all the ants within some radius of the blue turtle? That's the code I wrote in my first comment. But you perhaps mean on the same patch as the blue turtle rather than within a specified radius. I will do that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want all the ants (assuming ants is a turtles breed) on the same patch as the blue turtle to become blessed, do this:

```
ask turtles with [color = blue] [ ask ants-here [set blessed true] ]
```

If you want something else, please be more specific in your description.

Comment: So food is a turtle breed and ants is a turtle breed. I have tried wat you have written in your last comment, but then all the ants will become blessed and not just the one on the food.

Comment: Only the ants on the same patch as the blue turtle become blessed with my code. But it's still not clear - first you asked for the ants near the blue turtle, and now you are asking for the ants on the food. Which is it, or is it something like ants within some distance of food within some distance of a blue turtle?

Comment: I'm sorry! the blue turtle is the food. But I think I did something wrong with the code you gave me, because I tried it again and no it is working. Thank you so much!

Comment: welcome, glad it worked. With your clarification, the code is clearer as `ask food [ ask ants-here [set blessed true] ]`